# formatting table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table product that contains

```
Productcode  INformation
```

Infomration is XML type

```
<ArrayOfDonneesFormulaireType xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <DonneesFormulaireType LabelQuestion="Product" ValeurChamp="False" NomChamp="ClientHasAppointment" IsAffichable="false" />
  <DonneesFormulaireType LabelQuestion="Date" ValeurChamp="-" NomChamp="AppointmentCallingDay" IsAffichable="false" />
  <DonneesFormulaireType LabelQuestion="Hour" ValeurChamp="-" NomChamp="AppointmentCallingHour" IsAffichable="false" />
  </ArrayOfDonneesFormulaireType>
```

How can I get Table product like that

```
ProductCode   Product  Date Hour
```

I do it with oracle:

```
 dg.contenu_demande.extract('//DonneesFormulaireType[@NomChamp=''Product  '']/@ValeurChamp').getStringVal() as "ID_APPLICATION"
```

How to do ity the same within sql server?

Comment: Practically the same way, except SQL Server calls it `.value()` and needs an explicit type in the call. See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/xml/xml-data-type-methods).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`nodes()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type) method to query the Information XML then use the [`value()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type) method to extract information from elements and attributes, e.g.:

```sql
create table dbo.Product (
  ProductCode nvarchar(50),
  Information xml
);

insert dbo.Product values
(N'Foo', N'<ArrayOfDonneesFormulaireType xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <DonneesFormulaireType LabelQuestion="Product" ValeurChamp="False" NomChamp="ClientHasAppointment" IsAffichable="false" />
  <DonneesFormulaireType LabelQuestion="Date" ValeurChamp="-" NomChamp="AppointmentCallingDay" IsAffichable="false" />
  <DonneesFormulaireType LabelQuestion="Hour" ValeurChamp="-" NomChamp="AppointmentCallingHour" IsAffichable="false" />
</ArrayOfDonneesFormulaireType>');

select
  [ProductCode],
  [Product] = x.n.value(N'(DonneesFormulaireType[@LabelQuestion="Product"]/@ValeurChamp)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),
  [Date] = x.n.value(N'(DonneesFormulaireType[@LabelQuestion="Date"]/@ValeurChamp)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),
  [Hour] = x.n.value(N'(DonneesFormulaireType[@LabelQuestion="Hour"]/@ValeurChamp)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
from dbo.Product
cross apply Information.nodes(N'/ArrayOfDonneesFormulaireType') x(n);
```

Which yields:

```
ProductCode  Product  Date  Hour
Foo          False    -     -
```